How to map values in the array of arrays based on the second value in each array
I have the following data in the array of arrays:
[['apples', 2020], ['pears', 2020], ['apples', 2021], ['melons', 2020], ['peaches', 2021], ['pears', 2019]]

What I want as a result is this:
{ 2019 => 1, 2020 => 3, 2021 => 2 }

So basically how many fruits were available each year. Could you help me map this data please?

See Enumerable#tally getting to an Array of just the years should be fairly straightforward. What have you tried?

@engineersmnky I tried this each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |k, h| h[k[1]] +=1 } but I don't like the solution, thought there was something more "rails way"

Maybe explain where you obtained that data, since your question is currently a pure ruby question. If this data is stored in a database then there are likely more idiomatic rails solutions, e.g. FruitSales.group(:year_sold).count,  otherwise your Hash counter which can be expressed as {|(fruit,year),h| h[year] += 1} or using map(&:last).tally is about as conventional as possible in ruby.

Ah, no, it's not from the DB, just a result of some prior modifications I received from a client, not related to DB.

ary = [['apples', 2020], ['pears', 2020], ['apples', 2021], ['melons', 2020], ['peaches', 2021], ['pears', 2019]]
ary.group_by(&:last)
   .transform_values(&:count) 
# => {2020=>3, 2021=>2, 2019=>1}


Thank you so much! that's what i was looking for

map(&:last).tally although the original solution provided involves only a single iteration.

@engineersmnky yeah thats a pretty good alternative. I would go for whatever reads the best as this code probally is not a good solution for whatever the original problem is anyways.
